# Disable auto-formatting (IDE inserts braces, quotes, etc) in PHP plugin?

Tags: php, netbeans, quotes

Note that this is not about auto-completion or the excellent code formatter, Alt+Shift+F which I love.

Right, so I've tried to let the auto-close braces, brackets and quotes 'helper' grow on me. I've coded PHP in NetBeans for a few months now, and I love it. But for the love of Pete, I can't get used to it.

Especially, fixing up an echo HTML-line that is lacking one single or double quote is a terrible experience, same thing for when I cut out a few lines ending with a brace to put it below a code line that should be inside the braces.

I've gone through all the options, and for the life of me I can't find where to turn that off. Instead of growing on me, it irritates me more and more. I'll be happy to hack it, if there is some files where I can remove it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tools->Options

Editor->Code Completion

Language->HTML
**Quote-mark (") Keypress After Attribute Name Autocompletes Closing Quote**

Language->PHP
**Use Smart Quotes (" and ') Completion (after text selection, etc.)**

*The prevsious information has been overriden in the latest version, 7.4.*

> <strike>**Insert Closing Brackets Automatically** - When selected, the Source Editor generates the closing parenthesis, bracket, brace, or quotation mark after you type the first one.</strike>
>
> There are also some additional options under the Language dropdown for HTML and PHP.

Comment: Huhh? Thanks :) :rolls eyes: could have sworn it was disabled when I tested the quotes. Hmph. I am now in a huff and will stay grumpy until I get my ice-cream.

Comment: If you delete the first quote of a PHP string, and then type ", you get two quotes. So this issue is not solved, and the awesome creators of NetBeans (love it!) don't seem to get that some of us are capable of typing the code without unpredictable helpers and would like to turn it (ALL!) off.

Comment: @admin You are correct, I've updated the answer with the latest version of Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks, the amount of errors derived from quotes auto-handling is absurd in PHP. It should be disabled by default.